# How to wrap text around image that is behind text

Tags: css

This would be the situation, i'll try keeping it clear:

```
<div id="text">
  text...text...
</div>
<div id="image">
  <a href=""><img></a>
</div>
```

How can I show the image on top and wrap text around the image?

Thanks.

Comment: slightly off topic - if you want to get really fancy with your text wrap, you can use this jquery plugin. It allows you to wrap text around any shape. It's pretty neat. I've been dying for a chance to need it. [jquery bacon](http://baconforme.com/)

Comment: Seems ok, but I only need CSS. That means coding the php page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="image">
    <a href="#"><img style="float:left" /></a>
    text...text...
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but it is not the same HTML. This is the result that I want but using the HTML given above by me. Only CSS code needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to wrap your text elements in a paragraph tag, although both block-level and inline-level elements will wrap around a floated element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/UsvQd/

```
<div id="text">
    <div id="image"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" /></a></div>
    <p>text...text...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image { float: left; }
```